# PHP - pushing only key first to an array and adding values later

Tags: php, arrays

I have a foreach loop where I go through a collection of contents and I am making an associative array with values from a relationship of contents. This is the code:

```
    $contentTaxonomies = [];
    foreach($contents as $content) {
        foreach($content->taxonomies as $taxonomy){
            $contentTaxonomies[$content->id][$taxonomy->type->name] = $taxonomy->name;
        }
    }
```

But, that means if the `content` doesn't have any `taxonomies` it won't be in the `$contentTaxonomies` array, how can I make a loop that when it doesn't have taxonomies, it still gets add to an array just with empty value?

Comment: don't you think that when the `content` will not have `taxonomies` then the inner `foreach` will give error?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$contentTaxonomies = [];
foreach($contents as $content) {
    $contentTaxonomies[$content->id] = [];
    foreach($content->taxonomies as $taxonomy){
        $contentTaxonomies[$content->id][$taxonomy->type->name] = $taxonomy->name;
    }
}
```

Basicaly I initialized empty array as an value for a $content->id key and then eventually populate it with data.

Comment: Yes, of course, that is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

simply create the array before cycle thorough taxonomies:

```
$contentTaxonomies = [];
    foreach($contents as $content) {
        $contentTaxonomies[$content->id] = [];
        foreach($content->taxonomies as $taxonomy){
            $contentTaxonomies[$content->id][$taxonomy->type->name] = $taxonomy->name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$contentTaxonomies = [];
foreach($contents as $content) {
    $contentTaxonomies[$content->id] = [];
    if(isset($content->taxonomies)){ // This will check if `content` has taxonomies or not. Otherwise it will give error due to for each loop
        foreach($content->taxonomies as $taxonomy){
            $contentTaxonomies[$content->id][$taxonomy->type->name] = $taxonomy->name;
        }
    }
}
```